# wp8 Binding CheckBox to CustomMessageBox via DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

I make my own Control.
Inside that I want to define data template to use it in Custom message box.
In code I open this dialog but can't set start value to check box inside it.

Please help me - how to correctly bind cbVoiceAttChecked variable to CustomMessageBox via DataTemplate named VoiceTemplate

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myProj.RDPControl"
...
>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="VoiceTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Margin="32,0,0,0">
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbVoiceAtt" Content="..." IsChecked="{Binding cbVoiceAttChecked}"/>
            ... /*Other checkboxes*/
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    ... Here is main control - works perfectly
</Grid>
```

In code

```
public partial class RDPControl : UserControl
{
    public RDPControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public bool cbVoiceAttChecked { get; set; }

....

    private void VoiceButton_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        cbVoiceAttChecked = true; // This value binding to temlate!!!
        CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Caption = "...",
            Message = "...",
            ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)(this.Resources["VoiceTemplate"]), // Use template from xaml
            DataContext = this, // I want to use cbVoiceAttChecked variable to bind to dialog
            LeftButtonContent = "yes",
            RightButtonContent = "no"
        };
        ...
        messageBox.Show(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change your `cbVoiceAttChecked` property into a `DependencyProperty`, or implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `RDPControl` class.

You can find out more about the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface in the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN and about `DependencyProperty`s in the [`DependencyProperty` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) pages on MSDN.

Of course, it all depends on what you are doing with the `ContentTemplate` object inside your `RDPControl` class. As you did not show that, I cannot confirm that making the above change will fix your problem.

Comment: I try INotifyPropertyChanged - problem the same!